# JSF 2.0(Primefaces) - composite component is unreachable, if to refer by ID

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

Have simple composite component(compositeComponent.jsf),that is embedded to global.jsf page.

The problem is that ajax can't update this component.
Neither `:componentId`, not `formId:componentId` declaration doesn't work.

Should i write own method generator in my bean for id generation?

see pic. for more info!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open page in browser, rightclick and choose *View Source*. Locate the generated HTML of `<h:outputText>` and determine its generated client ID. You should in fact be using exactly this ID with the `:` prefix. Let's bet that the first part of the ID turns out to be autogenerated. This can happen if you didn't give your composite component a fixed ID. You need to do this as well:

```
<my:compositeComponent id="ccId" />
```

then you can locate it as follows:

```
<p:ajax update=":ccId:cCart:cId" />
```